# How to check if user exists given they have a user profile in Firestore

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'd like to check if the user exists in my 'Users' collection in Firestore so I'm not writing to a user that doesn't exist. I'm a bit lost with the documentation so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const express = require('express');

admin.initializeApp();

const db = admin.firestore();
const messaging = admin.messaging();
const app = express();

app.get('/checkUserID/:userID', async (request: any, response: any) => {
    const userID: String = request.params.userID;

    console.log(`Looking up user ${userID}`);

    try {
        db.doc("Users/"+userID).get().then((documentSnapshot: any) => {
            const userExists = documentSnapshot.exists;

            if (userExists) {
                response.set('Cache-Control', 'private, max-age=300');
                return response.status(200);
            } else {
                return response.status(404).json({errorCode: 400, errorMessage: `User '${userID}' not found`});
            }
        });
    } catch(error) {
        console.log('Error checking if user exists:', userID, error.message);
        return response.sendStatus(404);
    }
});

exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Many thanks in advance :D

EDIT: My issue is that I get a 408 timeout after about a minute.

Comment: What specifically is not working? Currently I only see that you are missing `.end()` from `response.status(200);` or alternatively use `response.sendStatus(200);`.

Comment: I get a 408 timeout after a minute and no result.

Comment: Aha looks like sendStatus() did the trick. Thanks @samthecodingman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I just needed to use `response.sendStatus()` instead of `response.status()`.
Thanks to @samthecodingman